# Bash regex and IFS split

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, wildcards

I have the following problem: I want to extract text that is inside brackets from a string (with or without the brackets). My string looks like this:

`STR="[1] [2][345] [678 9] foo bar"`

I initially wanted to use bash regex and BASH_REMATCH. I ended up using the following code:

```
regex='\[([^\]]*)\](.*)'
MATCHES=()
STR="[1] [2][345] [678 9] foo bar"
while [[ -n $STR && $STR =~ $regex ]];
do
    MATCHES+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
    STR=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    echo -e "matches: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -> ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

This kind of worked but my issue was that it would only capture one character inside the brackets, hence `[345]` would result in `3`.

I could not figure out why that was happening so I ended up using grep and PCRE after all. My current solution is

```
regex="\[[^\]]*?\]"
if [[ $(grep -o '\[.*\]' <<< $STR) ]];
then
    MATCHES=$(grep -oP "$regex" <<< $STR)
else
    echo "No special flags provided."
    exit 0
fi
```

I then proceed to a for loop:

```
for arg in $MATCHES;
do
    echo $arg
done
```

The problem is that it does not separate the fields as I would want them to. I used hexdump in order to find out the proper delimiter:

`hexdump -C <<< $MATCHES`

which, to my surprise, showed that the delimiter is in hex `0a`, the LF. That was not an issue as I know that for loop uses IFS for splitting. I then set IFS to LF by using `IFS=$'\n'`. To my (once again) surprise, that set the value of IFS to `0a0a`, according to hexdump again. So that did not work. I then set the value of IFS to `IFS=''` and that (for my third surprise) set the value to `0a`. But that did not work either, the for loop did not change behavior. Perhaps the scope of IFS was not set correctly by my script?

My questions are the following:

1) Why did the original bash only regex approach did not work? Why was it only capturing a single character? regex101 dot com showed the expected behavior, but then again, it does not provide a bash regex mode.

2) Why does the IFS set not work as I would have expected? It adds an "extra" LF, even when I set it to empty.

3) Why does IFS not seem to affect the for loop?

4) Is there a simpler way for me to tackle the original problem (extracting `[foo] [bar] [foo bar]` from strings like `[foo] [bar] 1 asdf[foo bar]`, in a way that I can loop for each bracket pair).

---

Bonus question!

B) I am confused as to when I should enclose a variable or expression in quotes or double-quotes. I have read a bit about globbing and parameter expansion and I am now looking for something more in-depth. Any recommendations?

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and all the questions it links to for your _bonus question_.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was an interesting read. I will keep those points in mind when writing scripts from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any non-empty string of characters that does not contain a `]`, use `[^]]+`.

Using `[^\]]*` would match a non-`\` followed by zero or more `]`.  This is why you managed to parse out the `1` and the `2` but not the other strings.

The `IFS` variable does not come into play in your first piece of code. Variables inside `[[ ... ]]` does not need double quoting.

To print the separate elements of an array, use

```
printf '%s\n' "${MATCHES[@]}"
```

or

```
for elem in "${MATCHES[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$elem"
done
```

Just `$MATCHES` would expand to only the first element of the array (and would apply word splitting and filename globbing to the value).

Comment: I see, my main problem was that I was trying to escape the brackets (hence the `\[` and `\]`). After removing the brackets and following your comment I got it working in a flash! Thank you for the help!