# Using regex with IFS variable to split Bash string

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, split

I am trying to split a string into an array by any character that is *not* alphanumeric. Can assign a regex pattern to the IFS variable to accomplish this?

I have tried it like so:

```
input="$1"

IFS="[^a-zA-Z]"
read -ra name_parts <<< "$input"
```

But this splits the string by any "a" or "A" - not even recognizing the "^".
[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503308/bash-regex-and-ifs-split) looks similar by title, but does not appear to be about the question I'm asking.

Comment: I should add that I am actually only concerned about alphabetic characters, so "alphanumeric" was inaccurate. I don't need to catch [0-9].

Comment: What is your expected output and your input string? Clearly this is an XY problem

Comment: This is an exercise for generating acronyms from names that may contain spaces, dashes, underscores, or some shell globbing characters. I am able to pass my particular set of tests with IFS=" |-|_|\*". I understand XY problem, but I wanted to understand the limits of using IFS, and think about how I might be able to solve it with an unlimited variation of possible delimiters. I read about IFS, but was unable to find specifics about that limitation. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFS` cannot be used that way. It does *not* take a regular expression. At the minimum, the characters (literal) composing the `IFS` is used by the shell to split words when it does expansion of words. E.g.

```
IFS=: read -r v1 v2 <<<"foo:bar"
```

What you have defined in `IFS="[^a-zA-Z]"` takes the characters literally i.e. each of `[`, `^`, `a`, `-`, `z`, `A`, `Z` and `]` are used as separators to split your input string which is clearly not something you would expect to do.

Answer (score 1):

`IFS` is just a bunch of characters (or bytes), not a regex. But you could use e.g. awk or sed to split the string based on a regex, print it out with a simpler separator and then read it with the shell's `read`.

```
read -ra name_parts < <(awk -vFS='[^a-zA-Z]' -vOFS=' ' '{$1=$1; print}' <<< "$input")
```

or

```
read -ra name_parts < <(sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z]/ /g' <<< "$input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tinkering with `IFS`, you're better off mapping the  the input string and then splitting it using the default IFS:

```
read -ra name_parts <<<"$(printf '%s\n' "$input" | LC_ALL=C tr -cs 'a-zA-Z\n'  '[ *]')"
```

Now the array name _parts will hold the string sliced at the non alphabetic positions.